# My JQUERY AJAX success function not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hey guys Im new to programming, can you tell me what i did wrong? my ajax success function is not working. But it inserts data into the database tho. I dont know why this is happening.

I edited some things, still not working

This is my myjs.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ":submit", function(e){ 

        var url;
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        if($(this).val() == 'Log in'){
            url = 'login.php';
        }else if($(this).val() == 'Register'){
            url = 'insert.php';
        }

            if(/^[^\s@]+$/.test(username) && /^[^\s@]+$/.test(password)){
               $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        username: username,
                        password: password
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    //EDIT
                    success: function(dataResult){
                        var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                        if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                           alert('yesss');                  
                        }
                        else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                           alert("Error occured !");
                        }      
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert('no');
            }
    });
});
```

My insert.php

```
<?php

    include 'db.php';

    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    //EDIT
    $query ="INSERT INTO `accounts`(`username`, `password`) 
    VALUES ('$username','$password')";

        if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
            echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200));
        } 
        else {
            echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201));
        }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: `":submit"` < that looks to be a typo. The colon appears to be incorrect. What does the HTML look like?

Comment: i tried removing the colon and its not inserting to the database anymore.

Comment: Have you checked using your browser debug tools that your server actually returns a code 200 response? Assuming you use chrome, right click on the page, select inspect, go in network, select xhr. Trigger your ajax and check your request/response.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to get "something" in the success function you must echo something from the PHP:

```
include 'db.php';

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$query =mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `accounts`(`username`, `password`) 
VALUES ('$username','$password')");

echo "something";

mysqli_close($con);
```

You will want to modify your PHP so that you get meaningful messages back.

**WARNINGS!**

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

**Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: i edited some things according to your suggestion but i still get nothing..

Comment: Open the browser's developer console and add `console.log(dataResult);` as the first line in your success function.